# How to separate a rotated text box into two in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I have this rotated area type shape and I would like to separate it in two parts, while keeping all the text as it is. It seems to me like there is no simple way to do this in illustrator. What I'm trying to achieve is outlined in the two images below, which I composed in photoshop.

[image]

First, to make any modifications to the text area path, I have to copy the path alone, paste it, and do my modifications separately without the text. After I have divided the shape in two, then I can start adding the text again, which as you know, would just write itself horizontally along the shape.

[image]

Now, I could just rotate the shape, write the text, then rotate it back again, since this is an easy shape and an easy angle of rotation. But there has to be a simpler way to do this whole procedure, especially when dealing with more difficult shapes and obscure angles of rotation, no? Does anyone know of an easier way?

Comment: Uh is it really that hard to duplicate it and change the content?

Comment: Yes, I know that is the first thing that comes to mind, but how do you deal with all the new lines? Let's say I made a copy and deleted "Separate this part". This copy works, since the text I want is at the beginning. But in the second copy, where I want to keep the ending text at the EXACT SAME POSITION relative to the shape, the text I want is at the end, and I will have to create two empty lines to keep it there. If I modify the path then, the text becomes overset, and is no longer visible. I hope it was clear. If not, I will edit the post with images.

Comment: Ah I see. Nothing is coming to mind then without expanding it

Comment: Seems using Point Text would be better than area text. I don't see a need for area text.

Comment: @Scott You're right, in this case it would be better, and I think that's what I ended up using. But I just thought to ask, in case I did need to do it this way later on, as I imagine would be the case if there was more text, a bigger and more specific shape, a specific angle and more need for structured control within the shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy:

duplicate your rotated text box (by the way don't just drag-and-rotate, that will cause your text to stay horizontal. Either tap <kbd>r</kbd> or Object > Transform > Rotate).

[image]

Delete all content in the lower box.

Click on the red **+** in the top box, the cursor will change to a **L** shape with lines, then click inside the lower box. The text now flows to the lower box.

[image]

Comment: This does solve what I was trying to achieve, but I have to expand on your answer. Because you cannot directly cut an area type shape, when I wrote the question I was copying JUST the shape path by itself to make the modifications and then retype the text within the 2 parts. This caused the path loses its text properties (including rotation). A better way is to place anchor points on the path before duplicating the area text. Those points can then be used as reference when modifying the shapes.

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off with a solution but if I understand you correctly there may lie an answer in the `Type > Area Type Options…` panel.

- I've set some type in an Area type box.
- Rotated the box so the type rotates at the angle of choice. Selected `Type > Area Type Options…`
- Made updates to rows and spans with paragraph styles.

Hope that helps

Comment: It seems like the perfect step in the right direction! But I would still need to split those rows or columns into separate paths to achieve what I want. Do you know of a way to do that? As in, I don't want to have one path with 3 columns or rows, I want to have 3 separate paths.